# Using InputStream and ZipInputStream in java

Tags: java, inputstream, zipinputstream

In Java, I am accepting an input stream from a webpage which happens to be a zip file.  I would like to unzip the file before saving it to the disk.  However, my zipInputStream.getNextEntry throws the following error:

```
"java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor"
```

Here is the code I am using.  This first part works fine:

```
URL url = new URL ("http://"+ipAddress+"/axis-cgi/record/download.cgi?diskid=SD_DISK&recordingid="+recordingID);
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((username+":"+password).getBytes());
String encoding = new String (encodedBytes);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoInput (true);
connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
connection.connect();

InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

This is the part of my code that is throwing the error (in the 'while' statement below). Note that unpack() writes to a file.

```
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
while ((zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    File destinationFile = new File("C:/Users/user1/Documents/folder1/test", zipEntry.getName());
    unpackEntry(destinationFile, zipStream);
}
zipStream.close();
```

What is the error saying only deflated entries can have an EXT?  Does this mean that the file I'm receiving is not actually a zip (ie it is a regular folder)?  I tried saving the InputStream directly using File, but the result is a file that my computer does not recognize.

Comment: Check this comment on SO [how to unzip an encrypted ODT OpenDocument in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10034902/2581401). It seems `ZipInputStream` has a problem handling a zip with uncompressed files in it

Comment: Ah.  I tried searching for something similar and didn't find anything.  That info let me go in a different direction, and I got it to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per the suggestion of c.s., I reviewed this thread. [how to unzip an encrypted ODT OpenDocument in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498554/how-to-unzip-an-encrypted-odt-opendocument-in-java/10034902#10034902).  To summarize, ZipInputStream has problems unzipping files that are in a zip file but are not compressed.